# Where is the Python distribution pre-installed with Wolfram?

Tags: python, external-language-cell

I am using the latest version 13.3, does Wolfram comes preinstalled with a python kernel/distribution?

I heard that some of the currently working features like sqlite connectivity uses python code, so where is the distribution of python that Wolfram is using, i.e. its location in the installation? I want to use python for some API connectivity and don't want to install another python if there is already a python kernel pre-packaged with Wolfram.

Comment: I believe that there is no such bundled Python distribution. From the docs: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ConfigurePythonForExternalEvaluate.html

Comment: I don't think that sqlite connectivity uses python code. It probably uses Foreign Function Interface (FFI, which call the library "libffi"). I think that because the documentation of FFI shows how to connect mathematica to sqlite, and I seem to recall that some videos about FFI(CEOing videos, there are 3 videos) mention the implementation of sqlite  connectivity with FFI.